# Search for a specific phrase only in the content and titles of Questions?

Tags: support, search

I would like to search:

1. only by the content and title of Questions
2. which contain the phrase "exactly two"
3. and which are marked with the [logic] tag.

Thus, I typed into the Search function everything in this box: $\boxed{\text{ "Exactly two" [logic] is: question }}$.

The Search function returned only 1 result: [How do I convince someone that $1+1=2$ may not necessarily be true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243049/how-do-i-convince-someone-that-11-2-may-not-necessarily-be-true/243081#243081) (Try https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Exactly+two%22+[logic]+is%3A+question).

However, I was actually questing after something like:
● [How to convert an English sentence that contains "Exactly two" or "Atleast two" into predicate calculus sentence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139378/how-to-convert-an-english-sentence-that-contains-exactly-two-or-atleast-two/139382#139382)
● and [Sentence such that the universe of a structure has exactly two members](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276036/sentence-such-that-the-universe-of-a-structure-has-exactly-two-members/276055#276055).

Why didn't the Search function divulge these two links? Should I have input something different into the Search bar?

Answer (score 3):

That is because you put a space between `is:` and `question`.

If you used `"Exactly two" [logic] is:question` with *no* space between the `is:` operator and the keyword `question`, you get [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Exactly+two%22+%5Blogic%5D+is%3Aquestion) which is precisely what you expected.

This is the same for **all** the advanced search operators: do not put a space on either side of the colon `:` mark.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/139378/) - which was on of the OP's example - is not among the results when I try your link. Neither is [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478236/exactly-two-or-exactly-k-from-english-into-quantificational-logic). Maybe the quotation marks used in the title of question might be the culprit?

Comment: When I try searching for *title:"exactly two" [logic]*, [I only get one question](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22exactly+two%22+[logic]). I expected this search to return the questions with the phrase "exactly two" in the title; several examples given in this posts are missing.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: that... might be a bug. It seems that it is not picking up on the quoted phrase `"exactly two"`. I'll ask around to see what's up.

Comment: [MSO link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195290/quotation-marks-break-exact-phrase-search), hopefully this will be fixed. Thanks for your sharp eyes @MartinSleziak

Comment: @WillieWong: Thank you. Could you please write again after the issue is fixed?

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thank you for mooting your question.